# Authentication error using SharePoint (Online) Migration?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, migration

Using SharePoint Migration Tool for document migration to SharePoint Online. Everything is going pretty smoothly, but for some unknown reason it keeps spitting back this error:

```
Task 5f91e154-64ad-4f64-bf26-c73368fcd77b did NOT pass the parameter validation, the error message is 'Username or password for target site https://{company}.sharepoint.com/sites/it-test-team/Temp%20Location/Forms/AllItems.aspx is not correct'
```

Have checked and doublechecked my credentials. I even changed my password (and updated it in my code) in case that was the issue. My guess is that something with multi-factor authentication is causing an issue. In order to login, my company requires the use of the Microsoft Authenticator app (I need to input a code that the app gives me). If that's the issue, how do I work that into my code? If it's not, what IS the issue?

Notes: I have the correct permissions (I am owner of the SharePoint Online site, I am running Powershell ISE as an administrator, I've set the correct Execution Policies)

Here's my code:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.SharePoint.MigrationTool.PowerShell 
$Global:SPOUrl = "https://o365gcoslo.sharepoint.com/sites/it-test-team/Temp%20Location/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
$cred = (Get-Credential ~my company email~)
$Global:SPOCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $cred

#Define SPMT task vars
$Global:FileshareSource = "I:\Applications\Temp_PTAX"
$Global:TargetListName = "Temp Location"

#Register the SPMT session with SPO credentials#
Register-SPMTMigration -SPOCredential $Global:SPOCredential -Force

#File Migration task
Add-SPMTTask -FileShareSource $Global:FileshareSource -TargetSiteUrl $Global:SPOUrl -TargetList $Global:TargetListName

Start-SPMTMigration -NoShow
$session = Get-SPMTMigration
#migration stuff here
```

Comment: SPOUrl looks wrong - should be "https ://o365gcoslo.sharepoint.com/sites/it-test-team/Temp%20Location" (ie, without the "Forms...." bit)